# How to align text in a tkinter Listbox

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox, alignment

I want to align text within a tkinter listbox. I have a list of dictionaries with reg. no., name, and email as keys in each dictionary. I have looped over the list and want the three attributes to be aligned in such a way, that there is equal distance between these words. So every word in every row has to start at the same position than the word in the row before / afterwards. But due to different name lengths, the alignment is disturbed.
In the code above, for simplicity i have just created 4 dictionaries for 4 students, but actually there are more than 50 students that I have to manage.
Also is there another simple way to display this data other than the list box, with the same condition stated above?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

students_Box = LabelFrame(root,
                    text = 'Registered Students', bd = 4,
                    relief = GROOVE, labelanchor = 'n',
                    font = 'Arial 10 bold', fg = 'navy blue',
                    width = 850, height = 180)
                            
students_Box.grid_propagate(0)
students_Box.pack(pady = 15)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(students_Box)
scrollbar.pack(side = RIGHT, fill = Y)

listbox = Listbox(students_Box, width = 90, bg = 'azure', font = 'TkDefaultFont 11')
listbox.pack(padx = 5, pady = 10)

allStudents = [{'Reg': '2018-MC-01', 'Name': 'Usman Khan', 'Email': '2018mc01@student.uet.edu.pk'},
            {'Reg': '2018-MC-02', 'Name': 'Muhammad Ehtisham Zafar', 'Email': '2018mc02@student.uet.edu.pk'},
            {'Reg': '2018-MC-03', 'Name': 'Ali Khan', 'Email': '2018mc03@student.uet.edu.pk'},
            {'Reg': '2018-MC-04', 'Name': 'Abdullah Akram', 'Email': '2018mc04@student.uet.edu.pk'}]   # A List of Dictionaries

for i in range(len(allStudents)):
        listbox.insert(END, f"{allStudents[i]['Reg']}     {allStudents[i]['Name']}{' '*20}{allStudents[i]['Email']}")

listbox.configure(yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.configure(command = listbox.yview)

mainloop()
```

Comment: You could use `ttk.Treeview` to show them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`string formatting`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) and fixed/monospaced font:

```
listbox = Listbox(students_Box, width=90, bg='azure', font='Courier 11') # use a fixed/monospaced font
...
for rec in allStudents:
    listbox.insert(END, f"{rec['Reg']:15}{rec['Name']:30}{rec['Email']}")
```

---

If you do not prefer hard-coded widths, you can calculate the maximum width of each column:

```
widths = {key:0 for key in allStudents[0]}
for rec in allStudents:
    for key in rec:
        widths[key] = max(widths[key], len(rec[key]))

for rec in allStudents:
    listbox.insert(END, f"{rec['Reg']:{widths['Reg']}}  {rec['Name']:{widths['Name']}}  {rec['Email']}")
```

Answer (score 3):

The direct way is to use `ttk.Treeview`.The solution under your circumstance(use `ljust` to fill them):

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

students_Box = LabelFrame(root,
                          text='Registered Students', bd=4,
                          relief=GROOVE, labelanchor='n',
                          font='Arial 10 bold', fg='navy blue',
                          width=850, height=180)

students_Box.grid_propagate(0)
students_Box.pack(pady=15)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(students_Box)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

listbox = Listbox(students_Box, width=90, bg='azure', font='TkDefaultFont 11')
listbox.pack(padx=5, pady=10)

allStudents = [{'Reg': '2018-MC-01', 'Name': 'Usman Khan', 'Email': '2018mc01@student.uet.edu.pk'},
               {'Reg': '2018-MC-02', 'Name': 'Muhammad Ehtisham Zafar', 'Email': '2018mc02@student.uet.edu.pk'},
               {'Reg': '2018-MC-03', 'Name': 'Ali Khan', 'Email': '2018mc03@student.uet.edu.pk'},
               {'Reg': '2018-MC-04', 'Name': 'Abdullah Akram',
                'Email': '2018mc04@student.uet.edu.pk'}]  # A List of Dictionaries

maxspace = len(max(allStudents, key=lambda x:len(x['Name']))['Name']) + 4 # add 4 spaces.

for i in range(len(allStudents)):
    listbox.insert(END, f"{allStudents[i]['Reg']}     {allStudents[i]['Name'].ljust(maxspace)}{allStudents[i]['Email']}")

listbox.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.configure(command=listbox.yview)

mainloop()
```

And it shows:
[image]

Comment: I have copy-pasted your code but when i ran it, it didn't give the required result. The issue remained the same. :(

Comment: @AdnanAkram Have you copied all the code?There are some differences in the `for` loop.

Comment: yes i have copied the complete code and have also seen the changes in the for loop.

Comment: @AdnanAkram What does it look like now?the same as before?

Comment: yes it looks like the same as before. I think its because of the font style. You haven't changed the font style.

Comment: @AdnanAkram :) Did you run the correct python script?It shouldn't be the same as before at least.

Comment: when I ran the code after changing the font style, it worked!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code. You have to use **Monospace Fonts** for the script to work

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

students_Box = LabelFrame(root,
                    text = 'Registered Students', bd = 4,
                    relief = GROOVE, labelanchor = 'n',
                    font = 'Arial 10 bold', fg = 'navy blue',
                    width = 850, height = 180)
                            
students_Box.grid_propagate(0)
students_Box.pack(pady = 15)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(students_Box)
scrollbar.pack(side = RIGHT, fill = Y)

listbox = Listbox(students_Box, width = 90, bg = 'azure', font = ('Consolas', 10, ''))#'TkDefaultFont 11')
listbox.pack(padx = 5, pady = 10)

allStudents = [{'Reg': '2018-MC-01', 'Name': 'Usman Khan', 'Email': '2018mc01@student.uet.edu.pk'},
            {'Reg': '2018-MC-02', 'Name': 'Muhammad Ehtisham Zafar', 'Email': '2018mc02@student.uet.edu.pk'},
            {'Reg': '2018-MC-03', 'Name': 'Ali Khan', 'Email': '2018mc03@student.uet.edu.pk'},
            {'Reg': '2018-MC-04', 'Name': 'Abdullah Akram', 'Email': '2018mc04@student.uet.edu.pk'}]   # A List of Dictionaries

MaxRegLength = len(max(allStudents, key=lambda s: len(s['Reg']))['Reg'])
MaxNameLength = len(max(allStudents, key=lambda s: len(s['Name']))['Name'])
print(MaxRegLength, MaxNameLength)
# MaxEmailLength = max(allStudents, key=lambda s: len(s['name']))

for i in range(len(allStudents)):
    listbox.insert(END, 
    '%s         %s          %s'%(allStudents[i]['Reg'].ljust(MaxRegLength), allStudents[i]['Name'].ljust(MaxNameLength), allStudents[i]['Email']))
    # f"{allStudents[i]['Reg'].ljust(MaxRegLength)}       {allStudents[i]['Name'].ljust(MaxNameLength)}       {allStudents[i]['Email']}")

listbox.configure(yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.configure(command = listbox.yview)

mainloop()
```